# Multiple types for a single variable (parameter/return type)

Tags: dart

I am very new to Dart so excuse me if I didnt see this part.

I want to make a union type e.g. for a function input. In TS this would be:

```
let variableInput: string | number
```

typedef doesnt really define types but functions and enums dont really help too.

On the other side how should it look like when a function return either one or the other of two types? There must be something I dont see here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are ***no*** union types in Dart.

The way to do this in Dart is returning/accepting `dynamic` as a type:

```dart
dynamic stringOrNumber() { ... }

void main() {
  final value = stringOrNumber();

  if (value is String) {
    // Handle a string value.
  } else if (value is num) {
    // Handle a number.
  } else {
    throw ArgumentError.value(value);
  }
}
```

See also: https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart

Comment: Some discussion about getting this feature in Dart can be found here: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/145

Comment: thats pretty sad. makes things so unnecessary messy. Thanks for the answer though.